# seeing what nth child a particular element corresponds to?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

Using the example at https://api.jquery.com/eq/, let's say I have the following HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li>list item 3</li>
  <li>list item 4</li>
  <li>list item 5</li>
</ul>
```

If you want to select the second `<li>` you can do `$("li").eq( 2 )`.

But what if I had a random `<li>` and wanted to see if it was the first? eg. Let's say I did `var el = $("li").eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1)` and then wanted to see if `el` was the first `<li>`. How would I do that?

Comment: `$("li").eq( 2 )` is the **third** not second since indexing is zero based

Comment: `[...el.parentElement.children].indexOf(el)`

Comment: Native DOM API: `el.previousElementSibling == null`

Comment: Or: `el.matches(":first-child")`

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether the element `.matches` a nth-child selector you're interested in. For example:

```js
const li = $('li').eq(2)[0]; // .eq is 0-indexed
console.log(
  li.matches(':nth-child(2)'), // false - it's the 3rd (1-indexed), not the 2nd
  li.matches(':nth-child(3)') // true
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li>list item 3</li>
  <li>list item 4</li>
  <li>list item 5</li>
</ul>
```

I prefer using plain DOM elements, but if you have to use a jQuery method to see if the element matches a selector, use `.is`:

```js
const $li = $('li').eq(2); // .eq is 0-indexed
console.log(
  $li.is(':nth-child(2)'), // false - it's the 3rd (1-indexed), not the 2nd
  $li.is(':nth-child(3)') // true
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li>list item 3</li>
  <li>list item 4</li>
  <li>list item 5</li>
</ul>
```

No need for jQuery, this is trivial without it:

```js
const li = document.querySelectorAll('li')[2]; // 0-indexed collection
console.log(
  li.matches(':nth-child(2)'), // false - it's the 3rd (1-indexed), not the 2nd
  li.matches(':nth-child(3)') // true
);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li>list item 3</li>
  <li>list item 4</li>
  <li>list item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is use `index()` to get an elements index within it's siblings.

You can also use `is()` and pass in a a selector or jQuery object representing a specific element

```js
const $li = $('li')

 $li.eq(Math.floor(Math.random()*5)).css('color','red').click(function(){
   const index = $(this).index();
   console.log('My index is ',index , 'is first = ', index ===0);
   console.log('I am first', $(this).is($li.first()))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li>list item 3</li>
  <li>list item 4</li>
  <li>list item 5</li>
</ul>
```